# Style an Action Bar in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'd like to set the background of an action bar (Honeycomb) using themes and styles. You can do it in code with `ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)`, but I can't find the corresponding style attributes.

I have tried using this theme and style for my `Activity`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

but this puts the background over the app icon and title on the left. The menu icons on the right are fine and the background is under it.

So is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I needed to inherit from the base action bar style. The correct styles are:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have the error here that '@drawable' isn't correctly spelled. Don't you know why?