# Android ICS: Remove blue divider in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working on an app which will be full-screen, but will utilize some of the functionalities of the ActionBar. With the Ice Cream Sandwhich release, I see that I get a blue line divider/separator as part of the ActionBar. Normally, it would be good for consistency, but in my case I need to remove the divider.

**How can I remove or style the divider of the ActionBar in ICS?**

Tried setting a custom theme with "android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar" as parent.
However, settings such as the one below has no effect

```
<item name="android:divider">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar
Also, did you remember to select your custom theme in the Manifest or your code?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The graphic asset containing the blue bottom line is the background of the action bar's container view and is set to `@android:drawable/ab_transparent_dark_holo` when using the default Holo Dark theme.

To remove this line, you'll need to create a custom style for your action bar (based on `Widget.Holo.ActionBar` or `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` (or the `.Solid` variants) and set the `android:background` to something that doesn't include the bottom border:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_background_here</item>
</style>
```

**Note**: Holo Dark/Light action bars have solid and transparent styles; this blue line appears by default for the transparent style. Holo Dark action bars are transparent by default and Holo Light action bars are solid by default.

Comment: the android:Theme.Holo is only for API 11. How can I do this for older APIs.

Comment: Note: setting `<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>` will remove the divider.

Comment: As @androider said only for API 11. To use it for lower API use support library v7. For the first block `parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light"`for the second block `parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar"` (or instead of Light Base or Dark) You will also need to use `<item name="actionBarStyle">` instead of `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to remove the divider, works from API 07 using the actionbarcompat from the support library:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whatever_you_want));
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the activity theme to Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar removes the blue line.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

If you still want a black background you may want to change android:windowBackground and/or android:textColor

Answer (score -2):

add this `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` to your app theme.