# How can I remove the divider between the ActionBar and the tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, divider

I'm trying to remove the divider between the ActionBar and the tabs but I did not succeed yet. 
I've tried this `<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/tab_color</item>` in my style.xml but nothing. 
In few words I'd like to have something like this:
[image]

Here's my style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyCustomTabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/tab_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar.TabView"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:width">30dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/tab_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTextColor" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

This is what I have
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it currently looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Theme.Holo.Light` has a default shadow on the bottom, so probably appCompat too, Try to use the default one `Theme.AppCompat`.

Your background use image, try to use a `@color/tab_color` like this.

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/tab_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/tab_color</item>
</style>
```

Sources :

[ActionBarSherlock issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/379)

[Removing line or divider in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584078/removing-line-or-divider-between-action-bar-and-main-screen-in-android)

[Remove divider under actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950839/i-want-to-remove-the-divider-under-the-action-bar)

[Remove blue divider on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704769/android-ics-remove-blue-divider-in-actionbar)

Comment: GOSH!!! Thank you!!!! Like you said the problem was that I used a drawable instead of a color.

Comment: Have they changed something in Android 5.0 ? This fix used to work before. I have applied a custom style with android:elevation property to 0dp. The shadow has turned to a thin line now, but still there. even after adding the above properties

Answer (score 2):

You can easily remove the divider by pasting this code in you styles.xml file

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

But according to [Googles new Tab design principles](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage), the tab strip is designed differently and there is also a different way of using colors.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the posted answers but for some reason they didn't work for me. This did:

```
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

I set those properties in my app's theme and it worked for me.