# How to remove the divider between two action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

How to remove the divider between two action bar 
one the application action bar and the other tablayout action bar

here is my current view i want to remove that divider 
[current view of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVzPq.png)
here by i have attached the style which iam using
`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="spinner_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/jc_border4</item>
</style>

<style name="tab_style">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dimen_16</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorCode3</item>
</style>
```

`

**MainActivity code:**
In which i have main action bar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Fragment code**
In which i have tablayout action bar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_style"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Apply `android:elevation="0dp"` to the first `Toolbar`.

Comment: @azizbekian i already tried it its not working

Comment: show your layout xml also.

Comment: **Check out this link i hope this may help you [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725086/how-can-i-remove-the-divider-between-the-actionbar-and-the-tabs)**

Comment: @SRBbans i edited my question and added my layout xml code