# Action Bar menu item text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-styles

How to change text color of menu item title. I tried to change it as below

```
<style name="Theme.Kanku.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

But it change color only of Action Bar title text, but not menu item text.

Comment: See this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar

Comment: Please refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35154585/1684864 It may helps you.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
<style name="ThemeName" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Note that this can be a ColorStateList as described here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html.

Comment: Any idea how you can programatically change the text colour? I have tried using a SpannableString with SetSpan(New Forground...() but it doesn't work.

Comment: I did not find the unqualified "actionMenuTextColor" was necessary (maybe that's something for Sherlock".  I did find that you MUST put the `android:actionMenuTextColor` item in the top-level Theme that's referenced in your manifest.  I had mine in the `ActionBarStyle` <style> group and it did NOT work there.

Comment: I had `android:actionMenuTextColor` it had default black color adding an additional entry without `android` made it work. Weird...

Comment: For Api21 and above use.....  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

Comment: I found Unqualified actionMenuTextColor is necessary to take effect on Android 5

Answer (score 110):

I tried several things but nothing worked for me. Finally this did the trick:

```
<style name="your_theme" parent="your_parent">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

I didn't use Sherlock themes. This worked for Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.

Comment: +1. Unlike the accepted answer, this worked nicely for me on Android 4.0+, using Holo.Light as base theme.

Comment: Anything else need to do? I add this to my styles.xml, but it doesn't work at all. I'm also not using Sherlock themes. This is what I did:

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MyTheme">
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    </style>

Comment: What does your styles.xml look like ?

Comment: At last, after seeing dozens of solutions that either don't work (for me) or are for ActionBarSherlock, this works.

Comment: That thing is so weird working but just don't know why. Close our eyes and believe.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! But seriously how can it be so hard to change the text color of a very specific control? And why are there so many different solutions that seem to work for some and for many others not? This is crazy!

Comment: This worked for me. I am using Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.

Answer (score 14):

After trying all of these and having them not work, I went about it programmatically like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.changeip_card_menu, menu); 
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menu.getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
        spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, spanString.length(), 0); //fix the color to white
        item.setTitle(spanString);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will work dynamically every time. In this case, the text color is changed to white. Simpy, change Color.WHITE to Color.whatever-color-you-want to change it to whatever color you want.

Comment: @kenyee which version of Android?

Comment: @kenyee interesting. I used this code in a 4.4.x app for work. It worked fine for me.

Comment: @Hammer which version of android?

Comment: @Hammer All right, I'll do some investigating and figure out why it may not be working

Comment: Worked for me. Style manipulation also worked, but I didn't find a way to change menu item color without changing action bar title color. However, this is weird.

Answer (score 7):

To update the menu item text color you need to make changes in themes.xml. The following answer is for sherlock.actionbar. In your themes.xml file add following lines:

```
<style name="Theme.Mytheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/mycolor</item>     
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/mycolor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Why is `item name="actionMenuTextColor"` necessary?

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/MyOverflowItemCollor</item>       
</style>

<style name="MyOverflowItemCollor" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

If AppTheme is android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar, then you need to set custom actionBarWidgetTheme in order to get action menu style changed. Like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBarWidget</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/{custom_menu_item_text_color}</item>
</style>

<style name="MenuItemText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/{custom_menu_item_text_color}</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarWidget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuItemText</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

please use the below code it works

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following line of code into your **style**.xml file that change option menu text color into **black**:

```
 <style name="optionMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>
```

Then add this one line code into your theme to change color of option menu text:

```
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/optionMenuTextApearance</item>
```

It works for me,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use DarkActionBar add below two lines in your style.xml

1. @color/green

   2. @color/green

Complete code is given below

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the action item color simply by following line

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/selected_text_color</item>
```

you can apply like this.

```
<style name="your_theme" parent="your_parent">
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/selected_text_color</item>
</style>
```

In my case

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/selected_text_color</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set color programmatically. Hope it help you.

```
private static void setMenuTextColor(final Context context, final Toolbar toolbar, final int menuResId, final int colorRes) {
    toolbar.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View settingsMenuItem =  toolbar.findViewById(menuResId);
            if (settingsMenuItem instanceof TextView) {
                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "setMenuTextColor textview");
                }
                TextView tv = (TextView) settingsMenuItem;
                tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes));
            } else { // you can ignore this branch, because usually there is not the situation
                Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();
                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(menuResId);
                SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());
                s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)), 0, s.length(), 0);
                item.setTitle(s);
            }

        }
    });
}
```