# Android ActionBarSherlock menu font color

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock

I want to modify the menu item's font color in ActionBarSherlock. I try few solution: [Action Bar menu item text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015010/action-bar-menu-item-text-color), [How to style the menu items on an Android action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar) and so on, but doesn't work for my app.

[image: My App ActionBarSherlock]

here is my style code:

```
<style name="onTime.ActionBar.Root" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/ic_actionbar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/onTime.Title.Root</item>
</style>
<style name="onTime.Title.Root" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_testing</item>
</style>
<style name="onTime.ActionBar.Default" parent="onTime.ActionBar.Root">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_grey</item>
</style>
<style name="onTime.Theme.Default" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/onTime.ActionBar.Default</item>
</style>
```

my menu xml (inflated in onCreateOptionsMenu() ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_update"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_update" />
</menu>
```

How can I modify menu font's color?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">    
<item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
<item name="textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
<item name="android:textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
<item name="textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
</style>
```

Comment: no, you misunderstand my question. My question is how to modify the menu font color, not ActionBar Title.