# Android: Toolbar color

Tags: android

I am building my first (material designed) app in Android Studio. I am following Slidnerd's Material design playlist, I'm up to #5. I wanted to know how I can have the menu popup to have dark text while have white primary and secondary text. Thanks!

Comment: what you want .. your Question are not clear..

Comment: I was wondering how I could have dark text on on menu popup, because I currently have white text on the popup.

Comment: check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015010/action-bar-menu-item-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

If i undestood your question, you need this:

**Set color of Toolbar in xml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@color/purple_800" <!--color-->
     app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
     android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

**And another in style:**

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gray_800</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/gray_800</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>
```

**and in values-v21 include this too**

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/purple_900</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/purple_900</item>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! All I needed was ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay. And BTW why doesn't your ActionBarThemeOverlay have a parent?

Comment: if i help, please give me that answer is correct :)

Comment: Yeah you did help. I didn't have this code.  <style name="ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>

Comment: i thought chek box next to answer, it award if someone help you :)

Comment: I don't see any check box :(