# Android Sliding Menu Options cannot be checked

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, menuitem, slidingmenu

In my App I have a sliding menu.

**My activity.xml looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/sliding_menu_options" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**The sliding_menu_options.xml looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black"
            android:title="@string/home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_recently"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_upload"
            android:title="@string/recent"/>
    </group>

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/otherItem"
            android:title="Other">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black"
                    android:title="@string/about"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_licences"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_description_black"
                    android:title="@string/licences"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

This picture shows the tutorial I used for my slidin menu and how the two groups should roughly look like. `Other` should be something like the headline or description for the second group:

[image]

When the user selects one of the four options, I want to mark the option in the sliding menu as checked. For the first two options it works fine with this piece of code:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

               navigationView.getMenu().findItem(menuItem.getItemId()).setChecked(true);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Unfortuantely the Menu withing NavigationView contains only two Items (`nav_home` and `nav_recently`) instead of all four. So it does not work for `nav_about_us` and `nav_licences` to mark them as checked.

**How can I check the other two options while still having two groups?**

Answer (score 1):

Looks ike there is a problem in **sliding_menu_options.xml** ,try following modified code .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black"
            android:title="@string/home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_recently"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_upload"
            android:title="@string/recent"/>
    </group>

<item
            android:id="@+id/otherItem"
            android:title="Other">
</item>

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black"
                    android:title="@string/about"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_licences"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_description_black"
                    android:title="@string/licences"/>


    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: The Other Item should be something like the "headline" for the next group. I added a screenshot above

Comment: To display the Other Item as "headline" , you can change the text color of Other Item inside onCreateOptionsMenu() method .

Comment: but Other will be clickable

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015010/action-bar-menu-item-text-color link to change the text color of options menu .

Comment: You can ignore/consider the click event for Other  item inside onOptionsItemSelecetd() , if you want to ignore Other iTem click then simply ignore click .