# Android change the title color in XML

Tags: android, xml

I have this part of the code in drawer.xml.

```
<item android:id="@+id/navigation_item1"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Map"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

I want to change the color of "Map" to white. I tried android::textColor, it doesn't work.  Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042794

Comment: Is that item `Menu item`?

Comment: @Stanojkovic  Yes    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group>
        <item android:id="@+id/navigation_item1"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Map"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>    </group>
</menu>

Comment: Read this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015010/action-bar-menu-item-text-color

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```