# Show Only Text as MenuItem in ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, actionbarsherlock

I've been searching for a way to add text as a MenuItem to the ActionBar. I've tried setting the icon to a transparent ColorDrawable and showAsAction withText but nothing seems to work. Is there any way to add text as a MenuItem?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't specify the `android:icon` of the menu item, it will default to the `android:title` given by you in the XML file.

Try this and replace the `android:id` and `android:title` accordingly:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_id"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_title"/>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Evan, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar

Also, please accept the answer if it helped you with your issue. :) Thanks!

Comment: How Can I replace the title dynamically, if I don't want to write in any string file ?

Comment: In `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, you will be able to retrieve a `MenuItem` object, you can simply call `setTitle()` on it.

Comment: any way to show the opposite...just show the icon and text is set to "gone"?

Comment: @Mike6679 You can always add an `android:icon`, and it should default to that.

Comment: use app:showAsAction="always" instead of android:showAsAction="always"