# Actionbar menuitem text is uppercase

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I have a menu item in my actionbar that shows only the text of the item - not the icon. And all is ok but just somehow the title of the item is going uppercase. can Can someone tell me how can I get it back to be as defined.
Here is the menu xml i have:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_download"
            android:orderInCategory="99"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="Download"/>

    </menu>
```

and I get an Item displayed as `DOWNLOAD` instead of `Download`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This one helped me (I'm using AppCompat)

```
<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton</item>

<style name="AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i have same problem i used your code but it not works.

Comment: try and put <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton</item> inside your base theme

Answer (score 7):

You have override the theme and set your own style for the actionbar menu items

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/LowerCaseMenuTextAppearance</item>
    </style>
    <style name="LowerCaseMenuTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

This post might be helpful [How to style the menu items on an Android action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar)

Basicly, what you will need to do is to apply a style to your menu item. In the style, add

```
android:capitalize="none"
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That'll affect ALL texts in your theme meaning all `Button`s and all `TextView`s, so this is definitely not a good approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32757893/882251 is the best approach.