# Android Change Action Bar menu text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am new at Android, I am getting in Android action bar menu text is capital form but I want the text `Change#0333` like I described in the following example image. Please how can I achieve this? Thanks.

[image]

This is my Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    menu.getItem(0).setTitle("change#0" + defaultmsisdn.substring(2));

    return true;
}
```

And this is my main.xml file in res/menu folder:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.ufoneselfcare.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/change_number_menu"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style the menu items on an Android action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and hope it's worked:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

menu.getItem(0).setTitle(Html.fromHtml( "<u>change#0" + defaultmsisdn.substring(2)+"</u>"));

return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your app's theme (in `styles.xml`), you will have an app theme, which you can customise. A blank one might look a bit like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>
```

What you need to do in order to have lowercase menu items is to use the attribute `actionMenuTextAppearance`, so using the above example, you will end up with something like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```