# Create a navigation right action button with AppCompatActivity w/ Text - Android?

Tags: java, android

How do you create a right action button in the Navigation bar - getSupportActionBar() that only contains text and no image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="Next"/>
</menu>

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_next, menu);
         return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_next:
            // .. do your thing
            return true;
        // ... other actions
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Right now my activity extends:  "extends AppCompatActivity",  what would I have to extend to override the onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity, which extends Activity, which defines the method.  You shouldn't need to change anything with your activity.  You should be able to just put your override for onCreateOptionsMenu right in your activity.

Comment: It throws this error:  (Menu) in Activity cannot be applied to (Menu, android.view.MenuInflater)

Comment: Ah. You must be using API 23.  I updated my answer to work with your project.

Comment: Awesome, that was it!  Quick side question though, in the XML I'm trying to set the color to: android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary",  that doesn't appear to work and it's all white.  When I call this in the Java code:  

actionBarToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));  It changes the title and the back button color to the primary color.  How do I set the item text color?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar