# Custom Style for Popup Menu

Tags: android, popup, android-menu, popupmenu, android-popupwindow

I am stuck with the problem on how to make a custom style for Popup Menu.

All I got is this kind of Popup Menu:

This is running on an Marshmallow emulator.

I don't have a custom style for this because I don't really know how to do it.

[image]

And here is my popup.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/popupMenuEditItem"
    android:icon="@drawable/edit"
    android:title="Edit Item" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/popupMenuDeleteItem"
    android:icon="@drawable/fab_menu_delete"
    android:title="Delete Item" />

</menu>
```

My goal is to have this popup menu,

[image]

Anyone know how to do it? I would really appreciate any help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072226/how-to-style-the-menu-items-on-an-android-action-bar

Comment: Thanks Sir but it's not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can have custom popup window in this case which will automatically get popup below or above view depending upon the clicked view position.

Reference link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: Is this the one used in the second picture I've shown?

Comment: yes kind off depends on how the development has been done.